# Pass contents of stringstream to function taking char* as argument

Tags: c++, char, argument-passing, stringstream, const-char

I have a function for writing ppm files (a picture format) to disk. It takes the filename as a char* array. In my main function, I put together a filename using a stringstream and the << operator. Then, I want to pass the results of this to my ppm function. I've seen this discussed elsewhere, often with very convoluted looking methods (many in-between conversion steps).

What I've done is shown in the code below, and the tricky part that others usually do in many steps with temp variables is `(char*) (PPM_file_name.str().data())`. What this accomplishes is to extract the string from stringstream PPM_file_name with .str(), then get the pointer to its actual contents with .data() (this is a const char*), then cast that to a regular (char*). More complete example below.

I've found the following to work fine so far, but it makes me uneasy because usually when other people have done something in a seemingly more convoluted way, it's because that's a safer way to do it. So, can anyone tell me if what I'm doing here is safe and also how portable is it?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // String stream to hold the file name so I can create it from a series of other variable
    stringstream PPM_file_name; 

    // ... a bunch of other code where int ccd_num and string cur_id_str are created and initialized

    // Assemble the file name
    PPM_file_name << "ccd" << ccd_num << "_" << cur_id_str << ".ppm";

    // From PPM_file_name, extract its string, then the const char* pointer to that string's data, then cast that to char*
    write_ppm((char*)(PPM_file_name.str().data()),"ladybug_vidcapture.cpp",rgb_images[ccd_num],width,height);                   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you actually changing the filename in write_ppm?

Comment: I'd suggest using `const_cast<char*>` instead of `(char*)` here, just to be clear on your intent.

Comment: If you're dealing with strings, you should use c_str() instead of data() to access the std::string object. c_str() appends a null character, data() does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a typical case of someone not writing const-correct code and it having the knock-on effect. You have several choices:

- If write_ppm is under your control, or the control of anyone you know, get them to make it const corrct
- If it is not, and you can guarantee it never changes the filename then const_cast
- If you cannot guarantee that, copy your string into a std::vector plus the null terminator and pass &vec[0] (where vec represents the name of your vector variable)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone. So, following a few peoples' suggestions here, I've done the following, since I do have control over write_ppm:

Modified write_ppm to take const char*:

```
void write_ppm(const char *file_name, char *comment, unsigned char *image,int width,int height)
```

And now I'm passing ppm_file_name as follows:

```
write_ppm((PPM_file_name.str().c_str()),"A comment",rgb_images[ccd_num],width,height);
```

Is there anything I should do here, or does that mostly clear up the issues with how this was being passed before? Should all the other char arguments to write_ppm be const as well? It's a very short function, and it doesn't appear to modify any of the arguments. Thanks.

Comment: This is the idiomatic way to solve the problem - if the function is taking a string that won't be modified, declare it as `const char *`. Then it will accept a string literal or a `c_str()` interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `PPM_file_name.str().c_str()`, since `data()` isn't guaranteed to return a null-terminated string.
2. Either `write_ppm()` should take its first argument by `const char*` (promising not to change the string's content) or you must not pass a string stream (because you must not change its content that way).

You shouldn't use C-style casts in C++, because they don't differentiate between different reasons to cast. Yours is casting away `const`, which, if at all, should be done using `const_cast<>`. But as a rule of thumb, `const_cast<>` is usually only required to make code compile that isn't `const`-correct, which I'd consider an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely safe and portable as long as write_ppm doesn't actually change the argument, in which case it is undefined behavior. I would recommend using `const_cast<char*>` instead of C-style cast. Also consider using `c_str()` member instead of the `data()` member. The former guarantees to return a null-terminated string

Answer (score 0):

Use `c_str()` instead of `data()` (`c_str()` return a `NULL`-terminated sequence of characters).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `const_cast<char *>(PPM_file_name.str().c_str())` ?

Comment: The function takes a `char *`, not `const char *`. Design flaw in the API I'd say.

Comment: Follow it up with a constant_cast then. It should be safer than a c-style cast of .data().